# What is wrong in C++ struct reading from PKCS11?

Tags: c++, struct, pkcs#11

I'm trying to use PKCS11 lib. I've got a wrong structure data on Windows10 x64 from C_GetInfo function.

#### My code

```
CK_C_GetInfo f_C_GetInfo = (CK_C_GetInfo)dlsym(__pkcs11->dlHandle, "C_GetInfo");
CK_C_Finalize f_C_Finalize = (CK_C_Finalize)dlsym(__pkcs11->dlHandle, "C_Finalize");

CK_INFO _info;
rv = f_C_GetInfo(&_info);
```

#### C++ declarations

```
/* an unsigned value, at least 32 bits long */
// typedef unsigned long int CK_ULONG;
typedef unsigned long int CK_ULONG;

/* at least 32 bits; each bit is a Boolean flag */
typedef CK_ULONG          CK_FLAGS;

typedef struct CK_VERSION {
    CK_BYTE       major;  /* integer portion of version number */
    CK_BYTE       minor;  /* 1/100ths portion of version number */
} CK_VERSION;

typedef CK_VERSION CK_PTR CK_VERSION_PTR;

typedef struct CK_INFO {
    CK_VERSION    cryptokiVersion;     /* Cryptoki interface ver */
    CK_UTF8CHAR   manufacturerID[32];  /* blank padded */
    CK_FLAGS      flags;               /* must be zero */

    CK_UTF8CHAR   libraryDescription[32];  /* blank padded */
    CK_VERSION    libraryVersion;          /* version of library */
} CK_INFO;

typedef CK_INFO CK_PTR    CK_INFO_PTR;

// Function C_GetInfo
CK_RV C_GetInfo ( CK_INFO_PTR pInfo );
```

#### Information from debugger

[image]
[image]

Wrong structure data starts from parameter `flags`, it MUST be 0 (Hex: `00 00 00 00`). But it has hex value `00 00 52 75`.

I can fix this error if I change type of parameter `flags` to `char[4]`

What is wrong? Why is PKCS11 interface wrong for this structure?

Comment: If you're using Microsoft Developer Studio 5.0 to produce Win32 stuff, this might be done by using the following preprocessor directive before including pkcs11.h or pkcs11t.h:
    `#pragma pack(push, cryptoki, 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two elements `cryptokiVersion` and `manufacturerID` take up 34 bytes.

`manufacturerID` mentions that its blank padded, if you look at the bytes, there is a series of `0x20` which is `UTF-8` for .

Followed by 4 `0x00`

Followed by `52 75 74 ....`

There is no padding in the data between `manufacturerID` and `flags`, but your structure definition contains 2 bytes of padding to align the `unsigned long` with the next boundary, which would be at `36` bytes.

Try removing the padding from your structure.

```
#pragma pack(push, p1, 1)

typedef struct CK_INFO {
    CK_VERSION    cryptokiVersion;     /* Cryptoki interface ver */
    CK_UTF8CHAR   manufacturerID[32];  /* blank padded */
    CK_FLAGS      flags;               /* must be zero */

    CK_UTF8CHAR   libraryDescription[32];  /* blank padded */
    CK_VERSION    libraryVersion;          /* version of library */
} CK_INFO;

#pragma pack(pop, p1)
```

Comment: It's ok. I've got correct structure data. But I'm wondering that I have to change pkcs11t.h

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was helpful. It helped me to find `#pragma` keyword in pkcs11.h. I haven't seen help information about it before

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely important to remember, that according to PKCS#11 all structures are packed to the minimal size, supported by the platform, and not aligned to 4 or 8 bytes. Not doing this makes PKCS#11 drivers incompatible with applications. PKCS#11 standard is strict on this.

Comment: Well PKCS#11 v2.20 specification vaguely states that _"Cryptoki structures are packed to occupy as little space as is possible. In particular, on the Win32 and Win16 platforms, Cryptoki structures should be packed with 1-byte alignment. In a UNIX environment, it may or may not be necessary (or even possible) to alter the byte-alignment of structures."_. One could say that packing with 1-byte alignment should be preferred on all platforms but in reality most of the implementations for Unix platforms use the default (not minimal) byte alignment instead.

Comment: For a real world example take a look at Firefox with its underlying NSS library running on Linux. It is using platform default alignment and ignoring 1-byte alignment "requirement".

Comment: @jariq and this is exactly the problem - half of vendors follows the standard, while the other half thinks they are the smartest (or the laziest). The result? Incompatibility of their drivers with the software.